# Fitting data for an implicit function with 2 parameters

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, implicit-conversion, data-fitting, minimize, model-fitting

I have an implicit function of independent variable **sB** and dependent variable **H** with two parameters **kV** and **km**, describing an chemical experiment. I tried to fit the experimentally obtained logarithmic points to the model provided by article using Wolfram Mathematica.
I turned the coordinates of the points into the values of the concentrations of sB(left) and H(right) for further use.

```
dotsA = {{0.5076923076923077, 7.751879699248121},{1.0153846153846153, 7.604511278195489},
{1.7769230769230773, 7.4},{2.576923076923077,7.209022556390978},
{3.2692307692307696, 7.070676691729323},{4.530769230769231, 7.003007518796992}};

dotsconcA = 10^-dotsA
{{0.310676, 1.7706*10^-8},{0.0965196, 2.48593*10^-8},
{0.0167139, 3.98107*10^-8},{0.00264897, 6.17984*10^-8},
{0.000537984, 8.49813*10^-8},{0.0000294599, 9.93099*10^-8}}
```

Constants and Model

```
kaA = 4.3*10^-7; kaB = 5.6*10^-10; kaW = 6.2*10^-8;
nA = 1; nB = 2; kH = 1; kW = 1; HB = 10^-7;
cBWA = 1*10^-3;
kV111 = 0.41*10^-3;
km111 = 13.1*10^-3;

kH*(HB - H) + kW*cBWA*(1/(1 + kaW/HB) - 1/(1 + kaW/H)) + 
(kV*1/2*(sB - kV - km + Sqrt[(sB - kV - km)^2 + 4*km*sB]))/(km + 1/2*(sB - kV - km + Sqrt[(sB - kV - km)^2 + 4*km*sB]))*
(nA/(1 + H/kaA) - nB/(1 + kaB/H)) == 0
```

Where kV111 and km111 are parameters that were obtained using the *Least Squares Method* in the article, but the article does not explain this in sufficient details, so I'm trying to find them on my own.
I found roots of function and made graph using parameters kv111 and km111

```
f1[H_, sB_] := kH*(HB - H) + kW*cBWA*(1/(1 + kaW/HB) - 1/(1 + kaW/H)) + 
(kv111*1/2*(sB - kv111 - km111 + Sqrt[(sB - kv111 - km111)^2 + 4*km111*sB]))/(km111 + 1/2*(sB - kv111 - km111 + Sqrt[(sB - kv111 - km111)^2 + 4*km111*sB]))*
(nA/(1 + H/kaA) - nB/(1 + kaB/H));

lst1 = Table[{-Log[10, sB], -Log[10, H /. FindRoot[f1[H, sB] == 0, {H, 10^-9}]]}, {sB, 10^-5, 1, 0.0001}]
```

and compared it to experimentally obtained points.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EHvg.png   This is a link to my plot from my question on Mathematica stack exchange

This plot looks exactly the same as one in the article.
I tried to fit data to model using the *FindFit* but it gives errors and values that not even close to found ones. None of the parameters and variables can be negative.

```
FindFit[dotsconcA, f[sB, H, kV, km], {kV, km}, {sB, H}]
FindFit:Number of coordinates (1) is not equal to the number of variables (2).

fdot1 = f1[dotsconcA[[All, 1]], dotsconcA[[All, 2]], kV111, km111];
dataA1 = Transpose[Append[Transpose[dotsconcA], fdot1]];
FindFit[dataA1, f1[sB, H, kV, km], {kV, km}, {sB, H}]
FindFit:The function value {0.0000237276+0.I, -0.0000526427+0.I, -0.00132824+0.00202876I, 0.0122705+0.I, 0.0152136+0.I, 0.0161337+0.I} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {6} at {kV,km} = {0.000352367,-0.0140961}.
{kV -> 0.000352367, km -> -0.0140961}
```

How can I find the kV and km parameters in Wolfram Math by myself?

**UPD**: So I tried the *LSM* that was given in the part 2 of article. This method implies that the sum of the squares of the differences between the values of H experimental and H calculated analytically should be minimal, i.e. as close as possible to 0.

```
f2[sB_,H_]=kH*(HB - H) + kW*cBWA*(1/(1 + kaW/HB) - 1/(1 + kaW/H)) + 
(kv111*1/2*(sB - kv111 - km111 + Sqrt[(sB - kv111 - km111)^2 +4*km111*sB]))
/(km111 + 1/2*(sB - kv111 - km111 + Sqrt[(sB - kv111 - km111)^2 +4*km111*sB]))*
(nA/(1 + H/kaA) - nB/(1 + kaB/H))

Sum[Log[10,
(H/.FindRoot[f2[dotsconcA[[i,1]],H]==0, {H,10^14}])/dotsconcA[[i,2]]]^2, {i,1,6}]
Clear[i]
0.0117239
```

Here I converted PH values to concentration and brought them under one logarithm. With the same **sB** value, we have two  different **H**s.
We must find this minimum by *manipulating* **kV** and **km** values.
I tried to use Manipulate to manually find **kV** and **km** and it worked

```
Manipulate[Sum[Log[10,
(H/.FindRoot[f3[dotsconcA[[i,1]],H,kV1, km1]==0, {H,10^-14}])/dotsconcA[[i,2]]]^2,
{i,1,6}], {kV1, 0.41*10^-4, 0.41*10^-2.5, 0.41*10^-4},
{km1, 13.1*10^-4, 13.1*10^-2.5, 13.1*10^-4}]
```

But this

1. Takes a lot of time,
2. gives not accurate results,
3. requires approximate ranges for manipulated parameters, which we
   don't know initially.

Is there a better way to find minimum of this Sum? I tried several "Minimization" functions but they're not working

Comment: Can you narrow this down to the first question that needs an answer? Is it that you need to find a way to figure out how the article finds kV111 and km111?  Or is it your kv111 versus kV111? Or variables not given values in FindFit? I'm trying to find the smallest possible thing that needs to be done with just a knowledge of Mathematica and no more.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my main language, I probably wrote the question incorrectly.
Yes, I want to know the way to find the kV111 and km111 parameters so that I can repeat it with other data.

Comment: Your use of English is much better than my use of any language other than math. Is the article available on the internet for me to read and try to understand and try to explain how to find kV111 and km111? Thank you

Comment: Actually, this series of five articles is not in the public domain. They titled "Kinetic Model of pH-based Potentiometric Enzymic Sensors" by S. Glab. Part 1 displays inaccurate formulas and we corrected them to our model above. Part 2 explains data fitting by model. We needed 3 part and I took all the constants, data and first plot for comparison from there.

Comment: I understand. I no longer have library access to journals. Perhaps a very polite letter to Dr. Glab clearly showing the work that you have done and asking if he would take a minute to explain the single step that you cannot understand might get a letter mailed to you showing you what you need to do. While you wait for that can you clearly show exactly the Mathematica code for the first step where you have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we found our fit and now I will describe how if someone will face the same problem. First of all, we simplified our model to a polynomial of the 4th degree.

```
f1[sB_,H_,kV_,km_]:=(H+kaA) (H+kaB) (H+kaW) (HB+kaW) ((-H+HB) kH+(cBWA (-H+HB) kaW kW)/((H+kaW) (HB+kaW))+(kV (-kaA (H+kaB) nA+H (H+kaA) nB) (km+kV-sB-Sqrt[(km+kV-sB)^2+4 km sB]))/((H+kaA) (H+kaB) (km-kV+sB+Sqrt[(km+kV-sB)^2+4 km sB])))
```

Secondly, we used Solve to find a solution for **H** and defined a function of **sB** and 2 parameters **km** and **kV**.

```
poly4[sB_,kV_,km_]:=H/.Solve[f1[sB,H,kV,km]==0&&0<=sB<=1,H,PositiveReals,InverseFunctions->True][[1]]
```

And finally the fitting

```
FindFit[dotsconcA,poly4[sB,kV,km], {{km,0.00001}, {kV,0.00001}}, sB]
km->0.006484, kV->0.0003568
```

Unfortunately, these parameters do not match those in the article, but when comparing the plots it looks great. Also, the fitting process takes about an hour, but that's a problem for the next question.